# "Also apply filter to matching conversations" gmail filter api

Tags: gmail-api

I have created gmail filter using API in c#.net. But when manually creating filter, I see there is an option called 'also apply filter to matching conversations', are we able to set this property while creating filter programatically? Or apply the filter to existing messages somehow? Basically the filter will set a label when received mail from particular user.

Answer (score 3):

### When you create a filter with the Gmail API, unfortunately you cannot apply it to already existing messages.

There is already [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/62715881) for this feature on [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). You can give it a "star" to increase visibility.

**In the meantime:**

You can work around by

- [Listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) messages - filtering them by specifying the query parameter `q`
- Applying the desired filter action to the listing results, e.g. adding labels with [batchModify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/batchModify)